# function to format dates not working R

Tags: r

I have written a wrapper function to format dates within a data frame to either a Monday or a Sunday using lubridate's floor_date function, and am receiving a rather opaque error message.

The function looks like:

```
week_format<-function(data,date,day){
  if(typeof(data)!="list") { stop("Error, data should be a data.frame")}
  ifelse(day=="MON",day<-1,day<-7)

    data$date<- floor_date( data$date  - days(1),"week") + days(day) 


  return(data)
}
```

When I attempt to use the function :

```
 week_format(dataset,wc_Monday,"MON")
```

I get error:

```
Error in slot(object, name) : 
  cannot get a slot ("call") from an object of type "double"
```

I am unsure what this error means, and cannot recreate it outside the function :

```
data$date<- floor_date( data$date  - days(1),"week") + days(7)
```

Works without error.

I should add data$date is already formatted as a date in R.

Here is a dput of the data:

```
structure(list(X.8 = 1:178, wc_Monday = structure(c(15341, 15348, 
15355, 15362, 15369, 15376, 15383, 15390, 15397, 15404, 15411, 
15418, 15425, 15432, 15439, 15446, 15453, 15460, 15467, 15474, 
15481, 15488, 15495, 15502, 15509, 15516, 15523, 15530, 15537, 
15544, 15551, 15558, 15565, 15572, 15579, 15586, 15593, 15600, 
15607, 15614, 15621, 15628, 15635, 15642, 15649, 15656, 15663, 
15670, 15677, 15684, 15691, 15698, 15705, 15712, 15719, 15726, 
15733, 15740, 15747, 15754, 15761, 15768, 15775, 15782, 15789, 
15796, 15803, 15810, 15817, 15824, 15831, 15838, 15845, 15852, 
15859, 15866, 15873, 15880, 15887, 15894, 15901, 15908, 15915, 
15922, 15929, 15936, 15943, 15950, 15957, 15964, 15971, 15978, 
15985, 15992, 15999, 16006, 16013, 16020, 16027, 16034, 16041, 
16048, 16055, 16062, 16069, 16076, 16083, 16090, 16097, 16104, 
16111, 16118, 16125, 16132, 16139, 16146, 16153, 16160, 16167, 
16174, 16181, 16188, 16195, 16202, 16209, 16216, 16223, 16230, 
16237, 16244, 16251, 16258, 16265, 16272, 16279, 16286, 16293, 
16300, 16307, 16314, 16321, 16328, 16335, 16342, 16349, 16356, 
16363, 16370, 16377, 16384, 16391, 16398, 16405, 16412, 16419, 
16426, 16433, 16440, 16447, 16454, 16461, 16468, 16475, 16482, 
16489, 16496, 16503, 16510, 16517, 16524, 16531, 16538, 16545, 
16552, 16559, 16566, 16573, 16580), class = "Date"), Payday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), Friday_Payday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Good_Friday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X.8", 
"wc_Monday", "Payday", "Friday_Payday", "Good_Friday"), row.names = c(NA, 
-178L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What do you need the argument `date` for? Could you also share `dput(data)`? On a general site using R function names as argument names (`data` or `date`) should best be avoided.

Comment: @thothal The argument date is there so the user can supply an arbitrary name for their date column and the function recognise it. Have uploaded a dput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have solved this by changing the indexation :

However I am unsure as to why this would fix the error if anyone could expand on the differences between `$` and `[,]` I would be grateful.

```
week_format<-function(data,date,day){
  if(typeof(data)!="list") { stop("Error, data should be a data.frame")}
  ifelse(day=="MON",day<-1,day<-7)

    data[,date]<- floor_date( data[,date]  - days(1),"week") + days(day) 


  return(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you should change your code to

```
week_format<-function(mdat, mslot, day){
  if(typeof(mdat)!="list") { 
     stop("Error, data should be a data.frame")
  }
  day <- if (day == "MON") 1 else 7
  mdat[[mslot]] <- floor_date(mdat[[mslot]] - days(1), "week") + days(day) 
  return(data)
}
```

And then you should call your function like this

```
 week_format(data, "wc_Monday", "MON")
```